# Shell Script not Starting java program [Debian]

Tags: java, bash, shell, debian, vps

I am using a shell script to run a minecraft server (based of forgecraft scripts) and I have got it working, but I then reset it to the correct java start line, at which point it stops.  The line that is causing the trouble is this:

```
java ${MEMORY_OPTS} ${JAVA_OPTIONS} ${JMX_OPTIONS} -jar $SERVICE nogui
```

Using Java -Version returns the java version, and the error I get is that the server dosen't launch, but when I use this:

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui
```

it does.

The reason I need to change to the above one is so my check server java file works for tracking teh server.
Thanks
- Thomas

p.s the script can be found here:
http://pastebin.com/2b0ki2NX
the check server java file and original script can be found here:
https://github.com/pahimar/ForgeCraft-Script/blob/master/script/minecraft

Comment: Do you get an error? If so, post it. :-) Also, what do you mean by "I then reset it to the correct java start line, at which point it stops"? Please explain.

Comment: Hard to tell what is wrong if we can't see the error message you get. What makes you think that line causes a trouble?

Comment: do you have Java on path? Try issuing command java -version in bash

Comment: The error I get is, when I use my own java line (java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui) the server starts in a few seconds, but when I use the line mentioned above, the program just says 'failed to start minecraft_server.jar.

Comment: java -version returns the correct java version.

Comment: Is there a stray newline in the definition of JMX_OPTIONS? See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 1):

Changing the JAVA_HOME seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably here:

```
screen -dmS mc$PORT $INVOCATION &
```

You probably need to pass the invocation command as a single argument:

```
screen -dmS mc$PORT "$INVOCATION" &
```